# Java Salesforce Integration Error

Tags: java, salesforce, integration

I'm trying to connect to salesforce from a java application. I was earlier getting a login error as follows which was resolved by setting the appropriate proxy settings.

```
com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/29.0
```

Now, I'm getting the following error:

```
com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/29.0/00D90000000q0ZR
at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:121)
at com.sforce.soap.metadata.MetadataConnection.describeMetadata(MetadataConnection.java:281)
at integration.IntegrationClass.describeMetadata(IntegrationClass.java:80)
at integration.IntegrationClass.main(IntegrationClass.java:26)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this error? Thanks!

UPDATE:  I tried the code at my home (free from the restrictions of the office firewalls et al :) ) and found that the code ran successfully. Any ideas about changes that I should make to do the same at the company. As I already said, I added the `config.setProxy(host, port)` which allowed me to successfully log in, but not access the application. I have also enabled proxy from eclipse using Preferences -> General -> Network Connections. What am I missing?

Thanks a lot for your help. Cheers!

Comment: this looks like the request isn't being sent at all. Can you through your browser, check if a connection attempt was made. You can check it through ->Setup->My personal information->Login History

Comment: @jimbo I'm seeing information as follows: Login Type is Other Apex API, Status is Success but Application and Login URL are blank. For the times when I'm able to successfully login using the API (at home), Application is Browser and Login URL is login.salesforce.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got the solution and it's kinda silly, but since I didn't spot it anywhere else inspite of seeing similar questions, I'm going to post the solution.

The `ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();` is used multiple times; in my case, it is first used to login using `new EnterpriseConnection(config)).login(username, password);` and next to obtain a metadata connection using `new MetadataConnection(config);`. Since I'm creating 2 ConnectorConfig objects, I would need to use the setProxy method on both, which I...forgot. Hope this solution helps other people having the same problem.

Cheers!